# Como eu posso pegar o erro 401 ao fazer um post usando axios com Reactjs em uma tela de login?

Tags: javascript, api, react, post, axios

Estou fazendo uma tela de login, tenho uma função que faz um post a uma API enviando usuario e senha, e recebe um token de volta de estiver correto (até ai tudo bem), ou retorna o erro 401, que é mostrado no console pra mim.

Queria pegar esse erro e jogar em um alert na tela, quando o o user ou a senha estiver errado.

Tentei assim:

```
 try{
              apiPost({
                username:this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password
              }).then((chave) => {
                this.setState({token: chave});
                this.setState({redirect: '/logado'});
              
              });
            
            }catch(erro){
              //console.log(erro);
              alert('Usuario ou senha inválidos!');
            }
```

Mas parece que ele não cai no catch, pois esse alert que eu coloquei nao é lançado na tela, talvez por que ele da certo, mas retorna com o codigo 401?

[image: imagem do console ao errar usuario]

Minha função API é:

```
export default function apiPost(data){
  
    return(
      axios.post('https://minhaapi/api/login',data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('RESPOSTA',response.data);
        if(response.status === "sucess"){
        return response.data.token;
        }
        return response.data.status
      })
    );
}
```

Tentei usar o status, sem sucesso, quando os dados estão certos, ela devolve o token direitinho, e eu faço o redirecionamento, quando da erro, ele mostra a mensagem no console, e só! quero informar uma mensagem, onde devo fazer isso ? e como ?

Comment: Poderia mostrar o código de sua api?

Answer (score 1):

Vou postar um código de exemplo mas com a mesma ideia do código que você fez:

Considere a função `apiPost` como o código abaixo:

```js
const requestQueDaraSucesso = () => (
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
)

const requestQueDaraErro = () => (
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(() => {
      throw new Error('401')
    })
)
```

Acima estou usando uma API fake só para explicar. Na primeira função teremos uma request onde os dados serão devolvidos, e na segunda, um erro, como se fosse a API devolvendo isso - só que ela retornaria um 401 no header e tudo mais.

Agora o código que chamaria sua função `apiPost`:

```js
const funcaoQueFaraRequest = () => {
  requestQueDaraErro()
    .then(resposta => {
      console.log('sucesso - ', resposta)
    })
    .catch(resposta => {
      console.log('erro - ', resposta)
    })
}
```

Como a função `requestQueDaraErro` é uma Promise, estou fazendo seu tratamento usando `then/catch`. Uma outra forma de fazê-la seria:

```js
const funcaoQueFaraRequest = async () => {
  try {
    await requestQueDaraErro()
  } catch (resposta) {
    console.log('erro - ', resposta)
  }
}
```

Dessa forma, você faz uso do `try/catch`, mas para isso precisa usar o `async/await` do Js.

Answer (score 0):

Não tá caindo no catch pois a ssua função não ta retornando nenhum erro. A função retorna um status caso seja diferente de sucess e esse dado não é considerado error pro tryCatch.
Coloca o tryCatch na function apiPost. Se a chamada retornar um erro, automaticamente vai cair no catch, ai você pode tratar a mensagem de error e exibir um alert.